# Kotlin Context Receiver with Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, kotlin-context-receivers

So, I've been researching about `Context Receiver` in `Kotlin`. And I've been trying to test it in my test project. The way that I'm trying to reach it is by applying `Context Receiver` with `Dagger Hilt`.

I have an `Interface` implementation like this:

```
context (LoggerApi)
internal class AnimeRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: AnimeRemoteDataSourceApi,
    private val localDataSource: AnimeLocalDataSourceApi,
) : AnimeRepository
```

And module like this:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAnimeRepository(
   remoteDataSource: AnimeRemoteDataSourceApi,
   localDataSource: AnimeLocalDataSourceApi,
   loggerApi: LoggerApi
): AnimeRepository =
   with(loggerApi) {
      AnimeRepositoryImpl(
         remoteDataSource = remoteDataSource,
         localDataSource = localDataSource
      )
   }
```

And the code didn't compiled with an error from Hilt:

```
required: LoggerApi,AnimeRemoteDataSourceApi,AnimeLocalDataSourceApi
found:    AnimeRemoteDataSourceApi,AnimeLocalDataSourceApi
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

And when i open the factory generated by Hilt. It looks like this:

```
public static AnimeRepositoryImpl newInstance(AnimeRemoteDataSourceApi remoteDataSource,
   AnimeLocalDataSourceApi localDataSource) {
      return new AnimeRepositoryImpl(remoteDataSource, localDataSource);
}
```

As we can see, the `LoggerApi` didn't get generated. But if i put the `LoggerApi`  as constructor, it build just fine. What is happening in here? I also tried to put the `Context Receiver` on the Interface but this still happens. Does this means `Hilt` doesn't support `Context Receiver` as injection or something else?